# How to extract some information from a link in JavaScript by using regex pattern?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is a example of my link:

> var eg="http://abcd.efgh.com/ar/1/55242/1?lt=9&adtype=3&pubid=5574988682&toolid=10001&campid=5337040086&customid=&uq=HO+scale+scenery&sellerId=&ex_kw=&sortBy=1&catId=&minPrice=&maxPrice=&laction=_self&ltext=Scenery&n3y=1&v1e=1&u7v=1&a3h=1&def=a3h&ig=1&mpt=366074929"

I want `pubid` and `campid` in variables by using regex pattern.

```
var pubid=5574988682
var campid=5337040086
```

Comment: javascript or jquery  ??...

Comment: Please share the code & logic that you have tried and got stuck. Thanks!

Comment: It is worth noting that regex questions without any attempt whatsoever are posted frequently onto Stack Overflow, and you may get a poor reception when making such posts, given that people will think you're asking them to do your work. Please always show your working, especially with regex questions. Let us know what you are stuck on in particular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try like this

```
// Read a page's GET URL variables and return them as an associative array.
function getUrlVars()
{
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}
```

above code taken form : http://jquery-howto.blogspot.in/2009/09/get-url-parameters-values-with-jquery.html

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
var queryDict = {}
eg.search.substr(1).split("&").forEach(function(item) {queryDict[item.split("=")[0]] = item.split("=")[1]})
```

And then:

```
queryDict.pubid
=> 5574988682

queryDict.campid
=> 5337040086
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try

```
regex = /.*&pubid=([\w-]{10}).*&campid=([\w-]{10})&.*/; //Regex

url = 'http://abcd.efgh.com/ar/1/55242/1?lt=9&adtype=3&pubid=5574988682&toolid=10001&campid=5337040086&customid=&uq=HO+scale+scenery&sellerId=&ex_kw=&sortBy=1&catId=&minPrice=&maxPrice=&laction=_self&ltext=Scenery&n3y=1&v1e=1&u7v=1&a3h=1&def=a3h&ig=1&mpt=366074929'; //Your URL

pubid = url.match(regex)[1];  //Get your pubid from first parameter
campid = url.match(regex)[2];   //Get your campid from second parameter</code>
```

You will get `pubid = 5574988682` and `campid=5337040086`

Answer (score 0):

For camp id RegEx is

```
(campid=)(\d)+
```

For pubid RegEx is

```
(pubid=)(\d)+
```

Where pubid= and campid= are strings and

\d---->Matches any digit character (0-9). Equivalent to [0-9].

+----->Matches 1 or more of the preceding token.